# Get items from list, write to word document and upload it into document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, custom-list

I want to get items from the List which matches my filter criteria and write these items into word document in tabular format.

For example, if i have `courseID`,`studentname`,`studentid` as columns in my list, I want to write those items which matches `CourseID=2` into word document in a tabular format and automatically upload it into document library.

I want to achieve this in SharePoint Online. I tried doing it with javascript, I found few code snippets to write to text file and upload it to document library.

Comment: Is this for archive purposes or for reporting?

Comment: It is for reporting. We want to see the list of students enrolled for courseID=2 (for instance) in a word document.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see a snapshot of what the list looked like on a given day, last year, I could see the need to export that, perhaps into a word document.

If you want to see the data live in a report, I would recommend building a view and providing the link to a "live" report.

Alternatively, I found this article that allows you to set up columns of SharePoint data that can be displayed in a word document.  I'm not sure about the 'automatic' creation on a schedule, but that was not in your requirements.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-external-data-columns-in-a-Word-document-bf0eca47-3ee6-42d3-bafa-2bdc7abeccb7

Comment: You're welcome.  Please mark as answer if this solves your dilemma.